# Using find_all to find a certain class in BS4 with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to find all of the top players "arena pts" (the in game competative point system) from this website: `https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/competitive/en-US/hype-leaderboard?sessionInvalidated=true`

I'm using requests to get the information and bs4 to sort through it, but I'm having trouble using bs4. Here's what I have so far:

```py
page = requests.get('https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/competitive/en-US/hype-leaderboard?sessionInvalidated=true')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('td', class_ = "asdt-points")
print(len(results))
```

When ran, the program outputs 0, meaning it didn't find anything.. from doing research online I haven't found any groundbreaking information that could help me, and I'm using stack as a last resort. Any help would be amazing! Thank you!

Comment: if you looked at the page in your browser, then you may have found the elements, but if they were loaded by JavaScript they wouldn't be in the original HTML that requests.get would return

Comment: take a look at page.content and compare to what you see in the browser. Also compare what you see using inspect element and using Ctrl+U in the browser.

Comment: @smartse I now see what went wrong here: When pressing Ctrl+U to look  at the source, and using Ctrl+F to find "asdt-points", nothing shows up! Printing ``soup`` shows the same information as Ctrl+U, so it seems I'm not able to scrape it... I'm going to need to use something like selenium maybe to see where the site is getting its data from. Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 3):

You wont able to do it using requests lib, because the page is asking api for those stats, which can be found in browser console "network" tab

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get('https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/competitive/en-US/hype-leaderboard?sessionInvalidated=true')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,features="lxml")
soup.find("div", {"class": "ApiStandingsDetailsTables"}).text
'Loading'
```

So instead lets just ask the api

```
import requests
api_url='https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/competitive/api/leaderboard/persistent/Hype_S14/undefined'
data_to_parse=requests.get(api_url).json()
resulting_list_of_dictionaries=[{'rank':i.get('rank'), 'name':i.get('players')[0]['displayName'], 'hype':i.get('pointsEarned')} for i in data_to_parse['entries']]

resulting_list_of_dictionaries
00:{'hype': 75434, 'name': 'Marzz_Ow', 'rank': 1}
01:{'hype': 50160, 'name': 'Its Filipе', 'rank': 2}
02:{'hype': 45821, 'name': 'たいちゃん0216', 'rank': 3}
03:{'hype': 42827, 'name': 'Fishy R2L2', 'rank': 4}
04:{'hype': 41806, 'name': 'Claw FA', 'rank': 5}
05:{'hype': 41379, 'name': '必ずアニキ救って来いやァァァァァ', 'rank': 6}
06:{'hype': 40511, 'name': 'えすぼん.', 'rank': 7}
07:{'hype': 39566, 'name': 'LG Slackes', 'rank': 8}
```

Comment: Yes! This is amazing! Thank you for doing this! How did you go about grabbing the api that has all of the info? I understand it was in the network tab of the console, using Ctrl+R to record all of the requests.. but where do you go from there?

Comment: I see now how you got the APi you did, google helps a lot lol

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that would require using selenium, since the table is loaded dynamically with Javascript. Bs4 can only work, and would work in your case, if the data were already loaded. What is happening is that when requests gets the page, there are indeed no td.asdt-points elements. you can see that by using:

```py
print(page.text)
```